# What is this British bomber?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, uk, bomber

From previous answers this is probably at RAF Duxford in the mid-1930s.

[image: British Bomber 1930's poss RAF Duxford]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Armstrong Whitworth Whitley]
Source: [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Armstrong_Whitworth_Whitley_MkI_in_flight_c1938.jpg)

I would say an [Armstrong Whitworth Whitley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Whitworth_Whitley).

Somehow the uncommon nose section looks like a special variant, maybe a radar-equipped submarine hunter?

Comment: The pictures show Armstrong Whitworth Whitley K7208, built as a Mk I, but used in 1938 as a prototype to test the aircraft with Rolls Royce Merlin engines. The nose and tail turrets were removed and faired over.